# Ubuntu 11.10 ATI Drivers vesa park

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-11.10, ati-mobility-radeon, vesa

This is probably not an issue, from all I can get it seems my hardware and drivers are properly installed. However when I go to system settings -> system info -> graphics. I get

> Driver: VESA:PARK.
>   Experience: Standard.

my graphics card is a: Ati Mobility Radeon HD 5470 512MB. I am pretty sure it's not a same-die GPU since there is a fan exhaust at the side of my laptop which I presume is the exhaust for the GPU...

I have no clue whatsoever what this means. I installed the ati drivers first using the 'additional drivers' method. However I also decided to look a manual installation up via the terminal since I've had problems before with Ubuntu and ati cards. I used `wget` and something among the lines of `sh dpkg -i`. I can recall exactly, I took them from another stackoverflow answer. Anyway, it seems everything is installed properly since it shows up with these commands:

1. `sudo lshw -C video`
2. `fglrxinfo`

however the first command seems to detect hardware, not the driver per se, although the driver is probably needed to detect the hardware anyway which would indicate its properly installed. I am still not sure about that VES:PARK thing though. I'd like to know what it means..

Also, if someone happens to know a good way of testing if the gpu is connected/being used...some sort of benchmark maybe...I'd like to hear it.

P.s. I can find my way around in Ubuntu but I would probably still be considered a rookie by more experienced users.

Answer (score 0):

I recently set up the exact same card in Fedora 16. 
In GNOME 3, you can check that fglrx (the ATI driver) is loading by viewing your Xorg log. (/var/log/Xorg.0.log on Fedora)

From what I understand from that log is that VESA:PARK is an ATI product.

```
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM: ATI ATOMBIOS
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 12.15
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2005, ATI Technologies Inc. 
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: PARK
[    30.422] (II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
```

Do you not have ATI Catalyst installed? You should if everything went properly and if you do have it installed you should be able to manage your video card settings.

VESA appears to be the GPU bios. Also, the fan exhaust on your laptop would probably be for your CPU, not GPU unless yours is built differently from mine.